# Nativescript listview on ios

Tags: android, ios, listview, nativescript

I'm using the listview which is built into nativescript in my android and ios app, I'm also using RouterExtensions.

On android, when I use `this.routerExtensions.back();` it sends me back to the list view where I was.

On ios, when I use `this.routerExtensions.back();` it sends me back to the list but it then jumps a few items so I dont get returned to the position that I was originally at.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I have no ios or android specific code in the listview or ts relating to this if this is any help

Comment: You could save the listview item position using application-settings -http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings and when you navigate back to the listview to use `scrollToIndex` to scroll to current index.

Comment: I'm trying to do it automatically though, like it does in android, without having to store a value